# YouTube BEDROOM Studio Microphone Upgrade: NTG3 to MKH 416 worth it?

Tags: shotgun, youtube, ntg2, ntg3, mkh415-t

I've been making YouTube videos for several years now.  I started with a Sennheiser ME 2 omni-directional lavalier, it was good but somehow there was too much RF in my room and I could never get rid of it.  I "upgraded" to using a shotgun that is about 7 inches away from my mouth.  The first shotgun microphone was the Rode VideoMic Pro and it was "okay sounding", but picked up a lot of room noise.  Then I upgraded to the NTG2 and noticed immediately the better noise isolation, and then upgraded to the NTG5 (gave better clarity and better noise isolation), and recently went to the NTG3 and fell in LOVE with the nice bottom end of the NTG3.

There are a lot of YouTube videos saying that the MKH 416 is the holy grail of shotgun microphones.  HOWEVER for my use of indoor video creations, in spare bedroom with no sound treatment... would upgrading to the MKH 416 make a difference?

Thoughts?

NOTE: I realize that most people watching YouTube videos are probably on a cell phone or Laptop, so they might not hear the difference... But I'm still curious if the MKH 416 would sound better than the NTG3 for use in an "untreated spare bedroom" studio.

Comment: if you're about to throw £750 at a new mic, why would you even dream of doing it without first hearing it? Rent one & see what you think of it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Tetsujin!  I actually just purchased a MKH 416 over the weekend!  I will be testing it out and make a review video to compare it to my NTG3 and NTG5 soon!

I SHOULD have rented the MKH 416 instead, do you know how much typical rental costs are for such a microphone?  Thanks!

Comment: That's always going to depend on where you live & your proximity to movie rental businesses. I'm in London, so there are lots, in tight competition. £15 a day seems to be going rate.